# JS function returning ''undefined' during a recursion call

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I am trying to do this problem where I have to add any 2 numbers in an array and the sum should be equal to a particular target number. I already did this using loops but I decided to do it with recursion as well. Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
  function findIndices(i, j) {
    const possibleTarget = nums[i] + nums[j];

    if (possibleTarget === target) {
      return [i, j];
    } else if (j <= nums.length - 1) {
      findIndices(i, j + 1);
    } else {
      findIndices(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
  }
  return findIndices(0, 1); //undefined
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return` in front of both recursive calls like this so that the recursively obtained result gets returned back up the call chain:

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
  function findIndices(i, j) {
    const possibleTarget = nums[i] + nums[j];

    if (possibleTarget === target) {
      return [i, j];
    } else if (j <= nums.length - 1) {
      return findIndices(i, j + 1);
    } else {
      return findIndices(i + 1, j + 1);
    }
  }
  return findIndices(0, 1); //undefined
};
```